# How to open a new terminal within a terminal in Windows OS with Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, process, operating-system, command-prompt

As I was going through it, it is possible in Ubuntu 20.04  LTS  by using command
 `gnome-terminal` ?

Is it any command in Windows For the Same. Explain the OS Scenario behind it.

Comment: Yes , I get it  Works with  start    command , but i didn't understand background scenario of Operating System in it , Means is it creating a Child process from that shell , if so then we close parent PowerShell then also child PowerShell is still executing (I am Learning , it may be misconception type of question to you.)

Comment: You need to @-mention others (e.g., @mklement0) if you want them to be notified of your comments, otherwise they may never see them. As for your question, please see the bottom section I've just added to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but here's a few pointers for *Windows*:

- If you're using **regular console windows** (`conhost.exe`):

  - To open another **`cmd.exe`** console window from `cmd.exe` (run `start /?` for help):

    - `start cmd`
    - Or even just `start` by itself.
  - To open another **PowerShell** console window from PowerShell (run `help` [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) for help; alias `start` works too):

    - `Start-Process powershell` (Windows PowerShell)
    - `Start-Process pwsh` (PowerShell (Core) 7+)
  - Of course, you're free to open a PowerShell window from `cmd.exe` and vice versa; just use the executable names shown above.
- If you're using [**Windows Terminal**](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) (run `wt -h` for help or see the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments)):

  - `wt cmd` / `wt powershell` / `wt pwsh`

    - Note: If you have created custom Windows Terminal profiles for your shells, use `-p <profileName>` instead of the executable name; e.g., `wt -p myCmd` instead of `wt cmd`, but be sure to specify the profile name exactly as defined, case-sensitively, otherwise the default profile is quietly used.
  - If you want to open a *new tab* in the *same window* (assuming you're calling from Windows Terminal):

    - `wt -w 0 cmd` / `wt -w 0 powershell` / `wt -w 0 pwsh`

---

As for the **relationship between the original and the new console window**:

- While the process associated with the new window *is* a child process (that therefore inherits the caller's environment variables),
- it lives on *independently* of its parent; that is, terminating the parent process (such as by closing the original console window) has no impact on the child process (and its window).